# Setting a C array as a new call stack (ESP) from inline asm?

Tags: gcc, x86, kernel, inline-assembly, callstack

As hinted from my title, I am interested if it would be possible to allocate a C array, and make it behave like a stack by pointing ESP register to it accordingly.

Some code example...

```
void foo(){
   int x = 99;
   int y = 89;
   return;
}
char myStack[1024];
void main(){
     int main_num = 66;
     __asm volatile("movl %0, %%esp": : "rm" (&myStack+1)); //Move ESP to the end of the array
     foo();
     return 0;
}
```

The idea behind this code would be to create sort of a separate stack, specifically for foo() by first pointing ESP to the end of myStack array (since stack would grow towards the lower addresses) and then have foo() called, have its return address and local variables now stored on this new stack (our C array).

I am wondering is such approach even possible? And if so how to achieve it?

While trying to implement above code I ran GDB just to see some info about my stack (ex: info stack command in GDB), I kept getting "No Stack" which probably means stack pointer was sent into abyss.

PS: I am implementing this as a kernel-level code

Comment: Maybe as a huge unsafe hack that only works in toy experiments.  If you want to set a new stack, do that in hand-written asm before calling a C function.  This hack could work for the call to `foo()`, but what about the `return 0;`?  Compiler-generated code will try to pop a return address from the current `%esp`.  (Actually first it might use `leave` and set ESP = EBP, then pop a saved EBP, which would switch back to the actual stack.  So the behaviour depends on optimization level!)  Use GDB to single-step your code an actually watch reg values change, e.g. with `layout reg`.

Comment: But yes, `&myStack + 1` is the address of one-past-the-end of the array, and does result in `movl    $myStack+1024, %eax` as setup for the asm statement (where `%0` expands to `%eax`).  https://godbolt.org/z/Nz6DgA shows that it "works" and will then immediately crash when it reaches the `ret` with optimization.

Comment: Are you hoping to access the stack contents via `myStack[i]` from other C code?   Or is that just a way to statically reserve space?  GCC is still going to assume that nothing can alias locals; there's no way to tell it that the stack is an observable side-effect.  e.g. it can still inline functions and keep locals in registers.  **What are you really hoping to accomplish here?**  Anything beyond using this static array as the callstack temporarily?  I don't think you mean using the callstack as a stack *data structure* (which generally requires hand-written asm).

Comment: Hi, yes it would primarily serve as statically reserved space. As an idea it seemed easier to do with C array, but from what I understand your comments it should be implemented in assembly instead?

Comment: And to answer the question of "What am I trying to accomplish". I am currently toying around implementation of threads in kernel level, hence idea is to assign separate stack for each thread, and shift between them. @PeterCordes

Comment: Especially if `main` has to actually `return`, then yes, you need to set up a stack *before* using it to `call` anything.  For example, under Linux the pthread library creates a new thread with a new stack by allocating it with `mmap()`, then passing that stack address as an operand to `clone()`.  So the new thread is never using the main stack, only ever its own stack.  The kernel side thread-stack creation for a new task is I assume similar.  You allocate a new stack, *then* use it for the new thread context.

Comment: That is kind of what I am going for, having thread using its own stack as opposed to main one. However, I do not have paging enabled and would like to implement stack creation as simple as possible for now (thus C array seemed like easy solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can work as a huge unsafe hack that only works in toy experiments. If you want to set a new stack, do that in hand-written asm before calling a C function.

This hack could work for the call to `foo()`, but what about the `return 0;`? Compiler-generated code will try to pop a return address from the current %esp.

(Or if optimization is disabled, will use `leave` which sets `ESP = EBP` before popping a saved EBP.  That would switch back to the initial stack. **So the behaviour depends on optimization level!**  You don't want that.)

Use GDB to single-step your code and actually watch reg values change, e.g. with `layout reg`.

But yes, `&myStack + 1` is the address of one-past-the-end of the array, and does result in `movl $myStack+1024, %eax` as setup for the asm statement (where `%0` expands to `%eax` in the template, because the compiler picked that register for the `"rm"` operand.  You didn't give it the option of an immediate constant or it would have just done that with `movl $myStack+1024, %esp`).

https://godbolt.org/z/Nz6DgA shows that it "works" and will then immediately crash when it reaches the ret with optimization enabled, because it tries to `pop` with ESP pointing at one-past-the-end of `myStack`.

> I am currently toying around implementation of threads in kernel level, hence idea is to assign separate stack for each thread, and shift between them

Especially if `main` has to actually `return`, then yes, you need to set up a stack *before* using it to `call` anything.  Otherwise that final return address will be on the wrong stack!

For example, under Linux the pthread library creates a new thread with a new stack by allocating it with `mmap()`, then passing that stack address as an operand to `clone()`.  So the new thread is never using the parent's stack, only ever its own stack.  The kernel side thread-stack creation for a new task is I assume similar.  You allocate a new stack, *then* use it for the new thread context.

You might put a "return address" at the top so the first function called in the new thread will actually return to a thread-exit / cleanup function.  Possibly with some asm for that.  Or make the actual thread entry point a function that doesn't return, instead cleanup up the thread context and switching to another thread or calling your scheduler or something.

> That is kind of what I am going for, having thread using its own stack as opposed to main one. However, I do not have paging enabled and would like to implement stack creation as simple as possible for now (thus C array seemed like easy solution)

Unfortunately this is too simple and doesn't actually work.

**Yes, you can use a C array for a thread stack (if you have exactly one extra thread...), the problem is how you're switching to it.**

You're going to need to write a context-switch function at some point which saves one register context and loads another.  (Google for example, you can find a few here on Stack Overflow, and probably something on https://www.osdev.org/.)

Create a new thread context struct in memory with its stack pointer pointing to the top of your thread stack, and its EIP pointing to the thread entry point.  Call your context-switch function to switch to that new context.

**From the POV of the C compiler, a context-switch function just looks like any other function call.  It returns *eventually*, and may have modified any globally-reachable C objects.  It doesn't matter that it temporarily had ESP pointing somewhere else.**  "Like any other function call" includes clobbering call-clobbered registers, BTW, so you don't need to save/restore EAX/ECX/EDX.  The caller of the context-switch function already assumes they're destroyed.

You should generally hand-write that in asm, not inline asm.  Changing ESP from inline asm is fraught with peril, and [is officially documented as not supported by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers-and-Scratch-Registers-1).

> This is because the compiler requires the value of the stack pointer to be the same after an asm statement as it was on entry to the statement

See also https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

Comment: _Create a new thread context struct in memory with its stack pointer pointing to the top of your thread stack_
What would be suggestion on how to create thread stack itself?

Comment: @Anton9988: a static array is fine if you have a fixed number of threads.  Like I said, the problem was how you're switching stacks, not how you're allocating it.  Just assign a pointer to `&myStack[1024]` to a `void*` struct member.  Otherwise you have to write a memory manager to allocate thread stacks.  BTW, 1024 bytes is not much; you might want at least 4k stacks.  Linux currently uses 8k or 16k stacks to make room for the worst case of complicated filesystem and virtual block-device code causing a stack overflow.